# Class de Lista Enlazada no reconoce atributo. "sum_value += l1.val AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val'"

Tags: python, lista, nodos, enlazado

El error del título me da cuando quiero correr el siguiente código. La clase ListNode la saqué de otro script, porque sino la coloco, me da el error de que no está definida. En el código original que lo obtuve de otro sitio, no está la clase y me ha respondido que si funciona. Podrían ayudarme. Gracias.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
   def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
       self.val = val
       self.next = None
           

def addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
   # Head of the new linked list - this is the head of the resultant list
   head = None
   # Reference of head which is null at this point
   temp = None
   # Carry
   carry = 0
   # Loop for the two lists
   while l1 is not None or l2 is not None:
       # At the start of each iteration, we should add carry from the last iteration
       sum_value = carry
       # Since the lengths of the lists may be unequal, we are checking if the
       # current node is null for one of the lists
       if l1 is not None:
           sum_value += l1.val
           l1 = l1.next
       if l2 is not None:
           sum_value += l2.val
           l2 = l2.next
       # At this point, we will add the total sum_value % 10 to the new node
       # in the resultant list
       node = ListNode(sum_value % 10)
       # Carry to be added in the next iteration
       carry = sum_value // 10
       # If this is the first node or head
       if temp is None:
           temp = head = node
       # for any other node
       else:
           temp.next = node
           temp = temp.next
   # After the last iteration, we will check if there is carry left
   # If it's left then we will create a new node and add it
   if carry > 0:
       temp.next = ListNode(carry)
   return head

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Example:")
   
   s1 = [1, 2]
   s2 = [3, 4]    
   
   print(addTwoNumbers(s1, s2))
```

El problema es la función, porque lo demás lo he agregado yo.  Es una lista enlazada y es de leetcode.

Comment: El error es claro, dice que una lista no tiene un atributos `val`, quizá debiste hacer `s1 = ListNode([1,2])`??

Comment: Tu función `addTwoNumbers` espera como parámetros datos de tipo `ListNode` pero tu le estas pasando unos de tipo `list`

Comment: ¿Porque en tu constructor en vez de usar el parametro `next` para asignar al atributo `next` le asignas de una vez el valor None: `self.next=None` en vez de `self.next=next;`?

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el programa vemos que creas dos listas Python comunes y corriente, y luego llamas a la función addTwoNumbers().

```py
   s1 = [1, 2]
   s2 = [3, 4]    
   
   print(addTwoNumbers(s1, s2))
```

Si miramos dentro de la función, vemos que estas listas son recibidas como  l1 y l2.

```py
def addTwoNumbers(l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
```

Aquí tenemos un primer problema, pues se ve que espera que l1 y l2 sean objetos del tipo ListNode, y en cambio estás pasando listas.

Después intentas ejecutar esta instrucción:

```py
       if l1 is not None:
           sum_value += l1.val
           l1 = l1.next
       if l2 is not None:
           sum_value += l2.val
           l2 = l2.next
```

y claro, l1 y l2 son listas, y las listas no tienen atributo "val".

*Solución* Reemplantearte que está haciendo el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que estás usando las pistas de tipado (lo cual me parece estupendo), haz uso de ellas con mypy y encontrarás el fallo. MyPy es un modulo de python que puedes instalar con pip y utiliza tus pistas de tipado para comprobar que el código recibe lo que tu le has dicho que debe recibir.

```
>>> mypy sotest.py
sotest.py:52: error: Argument 1 to "addTwoNumbers" has incompatible type "List[int]"; expected "ListNode"
sotest.py:52: error: Argument 2 to "addTwoNumbers" has incompatible type "List[int]"; expected "ListNode"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Te indica que el argumento de la función "addTwoNumbers" esperaba un objeto ListNode y le has pasado una lista de enteros.

Otra cosa, `next` ya es una palabra reservada en python por lo que te recomiendo que no la sobrescribas para evitar problemas en el futuro y si tu objeto solo tiene un método y es *self* quizás también quieras prescindir de él y usar solo listas.

Comment: La palabra next como atributo no está reservada. Lo que si está reservado es el atributo __next__.

Comment: Te estas contradiciendo. Pienso que lo que quieres decir el que el atributo next no está reservado pero sí el método. Lo que quiero decir es que para mí si una palabra la utiliza el entorno de python (sea en la forma que sea) para mí sí está "reservada" y debería usar otra distinta. De hecho `pylint` me lo declara como un warning: W0622: Redefining built-in 'next' (redefined-builtin). Python te deja hacer lo que quieras al final y es solo una advertencia, así que yo se lo dejo como recomendación únicamente.

Comment: Parece un comentario sin sentido el mio xD, es culpa del markdown. Quize decir que lo que si está reservado es `__next__`.

Comment: Que raro que te de esa advertencia, pues (que yo sepa) no redefines nada. Hay una función built-in next, pero no un atributo next.

Comment: No es raro, si tu declaras una variable llamada next, y luego quieres usar el método next que pueda heredar de otra clase ya no puedes porque has sobrescrito el nombre y acceder al método o a la variable se hace igualmente con el "." por eso la advertencia, porque puede causar bugs inesperados

Comment: Eso pasaría también con métodos como "fulano". Basicamente con cualquier atributo.

Comment: Pero no hay un método `fulano` en el entorno de python. Lo que el warning advierte es que ya existe un método [.next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) que si lo utilizas en tu objeto puedes causar bugs en tu código por la ambigüedad. Es como si sobrescribes `print`. Puedes hacerlo, pero no es aconsejable (y porque igual te avisa de que quizás estas reinventando la rueda). Ese warning no te salta si usas un atributo llamado `fulano`

Comment: Debe ser algo que pylint no contempla correctamente. El link que me pasaste es una sección de la documentación llamado built-in functions. Es decir, es una función. El problema aparecería al sobreescribir la variable next, no creando un atributo next.